# In html canvas, how can I make "new component" an unicode font instead of image?

Tags: html5-canvas

In the following code, I would like to use

```
function startGame() {
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "smiley.gif", 10, 120, "image");
  myGameArea.start();
}
```

any unicode font, for example , so how do I attribute? "font" instead of "image" is not working. Any help or pointer would be appreciated.

```
function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image") {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = color;
    }
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (type == "image") {
            ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
                this.x, 
                this.y,
                this.width, this.height);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;        
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText

Comment: thanks. however, I cannot move the font up, down etc like the gif